# Auto-reply for incoming mails to a distribution group Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007

how can i set a Automated reply email to the senders that send email to a Distributed email address?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way would be to set one of the users in the distribution group up with an auto-reply (you can create a service account/dummy user for this).

You could also set a mailbox up in front of the distribution group, with one rule to auto-reply and another one to forward the mail onto the distribution group.

Finally, you could set up a server-side transport rule to do this as well, but that seems like more effort than it's worth to me.